# How can I get my VB.NET forms application startup method to be Sub Main() in Program.vb?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-to-vb.net

Trying to get it to behave like C#, where there is a Program class with a static Main method.

However, in the project properties, I cannot set Program.vb to be the startup object, only the forms (it is a forms application).

Am I missing something?

I am using the VS2010 and the latest VB.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Uncheck `Enable Application Framework` in Project Properties.

Answer (score 3):

You need to switch off “Application Framework” on the main page of the project settings.

The application framework provides its own entry point which sets up a few things that are subsequently used (e.g. application events, single instance checks etc.) and then just displays the main form using `System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run`. That’s why you can only supply the main form, not a custom entry point method.